# Django admin save inline form instances with no fields

Tags: python, django

I'm attemping to add copies of a book through a books admin page.

Inside models.py I have:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...

class BookCopy(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        'Book',
        related_name='copies',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # No additional fields here



class BookCopyInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = BookCopy
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'copies'
```

Inside admin.py I have the following:

```
class BookCopyInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = BookCopy
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'copies'


@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (BookCopyInline,)



@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    list_display = ('isbn', 'title', 'subtitle')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    inlines = (BookCopyInline,)
```

I'd like to be able to add book copies inside the Books Admin page. But since the BookCopy model defines no additional fields the instances are never saved.

Adding a field to BookCopy and filling that in each time allows BookCopies to be created as normal, but I don't require any additional fields right now.

The image below demonstrates the issue I'm facing, new rows can be added, but when save is clicked, no BookCopies are created

[image]

Is there a way to have the admin save the instances regardless?

Comment: I would suggest that you tailor your database to your current needs i.e. a simple `PositiveIntegerField` on the `Book` model. Database migrations in Django are very powerful and intuitive.

Comment: I ran into the same issue when I stumbled upon this question. I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355406/django-admin-not-saving-pre-populated-inline-fields-which-are-left-in-their-init TLDR: the answer lies in the  `ModelForm.has_changed` method.