# How to force creation of unchanged django admin inline object in django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Fist things first - this is obvious duplicate of [How to force-save an “empty”/unchanged django admin inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657709/how-to-force-save-an-empty-unchanged-django-admin-inline)  but that question was asked 5 years ago and it seem so obviously needed functionality that i have suspicion that it may be addressed in some later django update.

So... do i still need to do this the way described in answer to mentioned question or is there some new, cleaner way to do this in django 1.9?

Comment: I agree, but i was hoping for some additional argument of something. Also it will save related model every time i edit parent without any reason.

Comment: If there is a "django way" to do this i would rather use it if not i will go the signals way http://stackoverflow.com/a/8750119 to avoid saving after every edit