# How to modify unchanged model admin inlines?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Kind of duplicate of both of these:

- [How to force-save an "empty"/unchanged django admin inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657709/how-to-force-save-an-empty-unchanged-django-admin-inline)
- [How to force creation of unchanged django admin inline object in django 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479551/how-to-force-creation-of-unchanged-django-admin-inline-object-in-django-1-9)

But I am still wondering is there any better way to do it in any later Django updates?

I aimed to modify my model admin stacked inline objects (pre or post save doesn't matter) when parent model admin instance is changed. I tried overriding `save_formset` and `save_related` in model admin class as written in Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related) using `commit=False`. For example:

```py
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    for instance in instances:
       instance.any_field = "value"
       instance.save()
```

The method `formset.save(commit=False)` returns inline form instances only if they are changed on Django Admin panel as mentioned in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method), but it doesn't return list of inline objects if they are not changed, even after sending `commit=False`. I need to edit those inline objects regardless if they were changed on admin panel or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a legit way of pre-save processing these unchanged inline forms. So I ended up doing post save processing.

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    super().save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
    forms = formset.forms
    for form in forms:
        obj = form.instance
        # Do anything with obj
        obj.save()
```